# MongoDB: how come these Date objects are different

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I am interested in getting a timezone offset in my `MongoDB` Date field. Using `MongoDB 2.4.9` on one machine, I see the following, which is the way I expect the Date to be stored:

```
NOVUSNYCLK67(mongod-2.4.9) test_salat> db.scala_date_test_1.find().toArray()
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5329bf52e4b089adba4e75ec"),
    "_typeHint": "com.novus.salat.test.model.Neville",
    "ennui": true,
    "asOf": ISODate("2014-03-19T12:01:22.355-0400")
  }
]
```

Note the `-0400` fragment of the `ISODate()` here. On another machine, it looks like the following (wrong way):

```
> db.scala_date_test_1.find().toArray()
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5329c755c026b6d16dc5972b"),
        "_typeHint" : "com.novus.salat.test.model.Neville",
        "ennui" : true,
        "asOf" : ISODate("2014-03-19T16:35:33.474Z")
    }
]
```

I'm using `Mongoid` to persist these dates (`Ruby` gem), but I just want to know how to get the timezone offset in my Dates so they are formatted like the following:

```
"asOf": ISODate("2014-03-19T12:01:22.355-0400")
```

and NOT like:

```
"asOf" : ISODate("2014-03-19T16:35:33.474Z")
```

Comment: The "wrong" ISODate is valid. The "Z" at the end signifies that the date/time is UTC. See the following for more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC

Comment: The comment above is correct.  Use UTC in databases it is bad practice to keep it localtime there.  Also your question is answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797470/how-to-save-a-timezone-correctly-with-ruby-and-mongoid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html):

> ### Configuration options
>
> Mongoid currently supports the following configuration options, either
>   provided in the `mongoid.yml` or programatically (defaults in
>   parenthesis).
>
> ...snip...
>
> - `use_activesupport_time_zone`(true): When in a Rails app will tell Mongoid to convert all times in the application to the local defined
>     time zone in Active Support.
> - `use_utc`(false): Instructs Mongoid to convert all times to UTC times in all cases.

Play with your `mongoid.yml` to configure the options correct for you. Also, see this question: [How to save a timezone correctly with Ruby and MongoId?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797470/how-to-save-a-timezone-correctly-with-ruby-and-mongoid):

> You will also probably want to set the following in config/mongoid.yml
>
> ```
> defaults: &defaults
>   use_utc: false
>   use_activesupport_time_zone: true
> ```
>
> This sounds counterintuitive, but this is the current way to make
>   mongoid use UTC as the default timezone.